# Migrating Servers - Where does SSIS look for Custom dll's?

Tags: ssis

We are upgrading servers from MS Windows Server 2012 to 2019, creating new servers and migrating applications as opposed to doing an insitu upgrade

SQL Server instances are being upgraded to SQL Server 2019 in the process.

I am migrating SSIS packages which reference some custom DLL's, to a new server.

In the source server the dll's were in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn`

On the new server I have copied them to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn` however I am seeing errors.

I have also tried them in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\PipelineComponents` but am still seeing errors.

I exported the SSIS project from the db, opened it up in MSVS on my laptop, compiled it and all seemed fine.

The main error appears to be

- `"Script Component - ResultSet" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN"`
- `The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully.`

My initial focus is to check that the SSIS packages are finding the dll's.

- Am I copying them to the right directories?
- Is simply copying the dll's to the directory enough?
- How can I prove that SSIS is picking up these dll's?

Any advice will be gratefully received.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

While I've not done a recent migration, you'll also need to have custom assemblies installed to the Global Assembly Cache, GAC.

```
gacutil -if MyAssembly.dll
```

The other thing I think *might* need to do is create a new version of your custom assemblies that bind to the new SQL Server interface.

Comment: @wp78de But SSIS has different version of their interface stuff so a dll built against the 2012 data flow runtime would not work with a 2014/2016 etc

Comment: I had primarily C# script tasks in mind. Packages sporting those kept working without recompiling in many cases for me. Anyhow, I think your verdict stands: 'might need to...'

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to work out the problem.

Firstly there were a number of script modules in the package and I had recompiled all but one, so that was a 'my bad'.

Secondly, in moving from Windows Server 2012 to 2019, the relevant directory is no longer in  `C:\Program Files`. It is now in `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

Once I had placed the dll's in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn` the package ran without error.

My thanks to those who responded.